# What does the double-hyphen do in `lxc exec`

Tags: lxc, lxd

Some tutorials (such as the [Getting Started](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/) on linuxcontainers.org) recommend the use of a double-hyphen (`--`) when using `lxc exec` to run a program inside a LXD container, as in

```
$ lxc exec my-container -- apt update
```

I suspect `--` tells `lxc exec` to pass provided flags to the program, because e.g. `lxc exec my-container apt list --upgradable` fails with

```
error: flag provided but not defined: --upgradable
```

However, I can't find any documentation on the issue. Can someone confirm, or clarify if that's not exactly what it does?

Also, I saw instances where people use `--` in different places, e.g.:

```
$ lxc exec my-container apt -- list --upgradable
$ lxc exec my-container apt list -- --upgradable
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partly this is a duplicate of [what does double dash mean](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash).

You ask an interesting question about `lxc` so let me answer that. In your two examples, both instances of `--` tell `lxc` to not interpret options after that point. The different positioning in this case is irrelevant. However, because you're running a command line in a container, you might want to use `--` as part of that command line. Consider the following: I created a file `/tmp/bar` containing the line `--foo`. The following commands were run in the container:

```
root@myContainer:~# echo "here is --foo" >/tmp/bar
root@myContainer:~# echo "this line has no double dash" >> /tmp/bar
root@myContainer:~# cat /tmp/bar
here is --foo
this line has no double dash
root@myContainer:~# exit
```

Now I'm going to search for that using `grep`. I need to let `grep` know that the `--` is part of the search pattern, not an option to `grep`:

```
$ lxc exec myContainer -- grep -- --foo /tmp/bar
here is --foo
```

If I use a single `--` it gets consumed by the `lxc` command line and I get the error:

```
$ lxc exec myContainer grep -- --foo /tmp/bar
grep: unrecognized option '--foo'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```